# numerical ifelse

Tags: programming

When I was studying machine learning, I came across the cost function for logistic regression written as:

$ Cost(h_\theta(x), y) = -y\log(h_\theta(x)) - (1 - y)\log(1 - h_\theta(x)) $

As a rewrite of the piecewise version:

$ Cost(h_\theta(x), y) = \begin{cases} 
      −log(h_\theta(x))  , y = 1 \\
      −log(1−h_\theta(x)), y = 0 
\end{cases}$

I'm now experimenting with this pattern ( $ y \ x + z \ (1 - x) $ where $ x \in \{0, 1\} $ ) as a programming technique to avoid using if else expressions for calculations.

from:

```
function calc(a, b, c) {
  if(a == 1) return b * 3
  else if (a == 0) return c * 5
}
```

to:

```
function calc(a, b, c) {
  return a * (b * 3) + (1 - a) * (c * 5)
}
```

My question is, does this pattern have a name? Is it useful? Is it common?

Comment: It can be implemented simply with the *Heaviside step function*.